# Idiomatic Client Libraries with Cassandra + PHP?

Tags: database, cassandra, thrift, avro

On this video (at 29:00), Eric Evans from Rackspace tells an audience that using Thrift and Avro is a bad idea. Instead, he advocates using the Idiomatic Client Libraries.

http://video.disruptivecode.com/video/840645/what-makes-cassandra-trick

We're primarily coding in PHP. How do we connect PHP with Cassandra without Thrift or Avro?

The Idiomatic Client Libraries that Eric mentions are:

- Pelops, Hector (Java)
- Pycassa (Python)
- Cassandra (Ruby)
- Others... ***which are the others?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cassandra High Level Clients](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ClientOptions) (The Cassandra wiki is a great place on earth)

In your case I would recommend Tylers Hobb's [phpcassa](https://github.com/thobbs/phpcassa).

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to check out the new kid on the block, unimaginably named PHP Cassandra Client Library: http://github.com/kallaspriit/Cassandra-PHP-Client-Library.

It's a powerful high-level client, hiding the quirks of Thrift and focusing on simplicity, performance and lean learning curve featuring:

- simple and intuitive interface
- well covered with unit tests (> 90%)
- support for multiple server pools using named singletons
- requires including a single file
- uses reasonable defaults through-out
- powerful syntax for querying data
- enables managing keyspaces and column-families
- automatic packing of datatypes using column metadata
- retries failed queries using back-off strategy
- built with performance in mind (caches schema description etc)
- well documented API and a working example

Comment: Any reason you have stopped developing your PHP client in 2013?